# How to limit the textbox input characters count?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

When I get my specific data from a `DataGridView` and I want to put it in `TextBox`, I want the `TextBox` to just accept 11 characters, not more.

How do I achieve that?

```
textBox3.MaxLength = 11;
textBox3.Text= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Phone Number"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: And?.... what is the problem?

Comment: Pretty sure he's saying the assigned text doesn't respect the maxlength property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) to truncate the string.

```
// Set the MaxLength, may not be needed if the field cannot be altered manually
textBox3.MaxLength = 11;

// Get the text value
var text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Phone Number"].Value.ToString();

// Starting from the first character, take up to 11 characters max
textBox3.Text = text.Substring(0, text.Length > 11 ? 11 : text.Length);
```

Example:

```
string longString = "abcdefghijklmnop";
string shortString = "abcde";
```

Result:

> **longString** would show **abcdefghijk**
>   **shortString** would show **abcde**

Comment: then why to try and set the max length?

Comment: I don't know if the user can alter the phone number after it's been populated. You're correct that if it's a read only textbox the maxlength property is not needed. Makes no difference really...

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to upvote/accept when you can :-)